# Vision-based hand gesture recognition in Android

Tags: android, computer-vision, augmented-reality

I want to know where it is possible to track the hand gestures(with wearing color markers) using Android camera?
I saw [SDK by Qualcomm](https://developer.qualcomm.com/mobile-development/mobile-technologies/computer-vision-fastcv). But I found no sample related to it!! Can anyone help in this?

Comment: How is yours experience with Qualcomm support, do they really care to answer question about their SDK?

Comment: @darkcrow I browsed the site!! nothing more that!! downloaded their SDKs.now want to start the app with some samples.

Comment: There is full-fledged link for discussion and forums too at Qualcomm website.

Answer (score 1):

The Qualcomm SDK comes with a sample application: https://developer.qualcomm.com/mobile-development/mobile-technologies/computer-vision-fastcv/compiling-and-running-fastcv-sample-app

Comment: Thanks @Nick!! Have you tried using Color markers in Android?